# How to filter a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = {'foo': 'x',
     'bar': 'y',
     'zoo': 'None',
     'foobar': 'None'}
```

I want to filter all the items whose value is `'None'` and update the `foo` and `bar` items with a particular value. I tried:

```
for i in x.items():
   ....:    if i[i] == 'None':
   ....:        x.pop(i[0])
   ....:    else:
   ....:        x.update({i[0]:'updated'})
```

But it is not working.

Comment: That's not the proper way to loop through a dictionary.

Comment: What are i and x? Your dictionary is named d.

Comment: It is `'None'` or `None`? String or a nonetype?

Comment: The confusion between `"None"` and `None` makes this question less useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not clear what is `'None'` in the dictionary you posted. If it is a string, you can use the following:

```
dict((k, 'updated') for k, v in d.items() if v != 'None')
```

If it is `None`, just replace the checking, for example:

```
dict((k, 'updated') for k, v in d.items() if v is None)
```

(If you are still using Python 2, replace `.items()` with `.iteritems()`)

Comment: @SilentGhost which one and why?

Comment: second one! because `None` is not the only falsy value.

Comment: well, I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 15):

it's not clear where you're getting your `'updated'` value from, but in general it would look like this:

```
{i: 'updated' for i, j in d.items() if j != 'None'}
```

in python2.7 or newer.

Comment: surely you are not comparing to the string 'None'? Or do you think the OP really meant that (as opposed to, say, the value None)?

Comment: @hughdbrown: The OP's example clearly uses the string value `'None'`(as currently written). Whether or not that is intended is something that only the OP can explain.

Comment: @hugh: OP's `d` is a valid dictionary, I've no reason to think that `'None'` is actually `None`

Comment: Hmmmm. That is messed up. Removing my post.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
>>> for x in [x for x in d.keys() if d[x] == 'None']:
        d.pop(x)
```

Comment: you don't need `.keys()` there

Comment: @SilentGhost, i think `d.keys()` is needed here, because it returns a new list, otherwise he would be iterating over a dict which is changing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a general filter function:

```
def filter(dict, by_key = lambda x: True, by_value = lambda x: True):
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if (by_key(k) and by_value(v)):
            yield (k, v)
```

or

```
def filter(dict, by_key = lambda x: True, by_value = lambda x: True):
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in dict.items() if by_key(k) and by_value(v))
```

and then you can do this:

```
new_d = dict(filter(d, by_key = lambda k: k != 'None'))
```

Note that this was written to be compatible with Python 3. Mileage may vary.

The cool thing about this is that it allows you to pass arbitrary lambdas in to filter instead of hard-coding a particular condition. Plus, it's not any slower than any of the other solutions here. Furthermore, if you use the first solution I provided then you can iterate over the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_d = dict((k, 'updated') for k, v in d.iteritems() if k != 'None')
```